# Equality of two shuffling codes in R

Tags: r, random, sample, sampling

I was wondering if the following two shufflings of 4 numbers (`1:4`) are equally random or one is perhaps preferred to the other in terms of randomness:

```
sample(rep(1:4, 10))

replicate(10, sample(1:4))
```

#### Constraint:

Despite randomness, I need to have equal number of 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s.

Comment: I'm not sure this is necessarily a developer question as much as it is a research question. `set.seed()` will contribute to randomness, although I'm not sure seed influences functions like `sample`.

Comment: I believe that they're equally random, but the first line will be much faster because it doesn't need to restart the random number generator as often.

Comment: @OTStats, just run `set.seed(1701); sample(1:100, 1)` multiple times. It will produce the same result, `13`, every time.

Comment: Well, they return different objects (one a vector and one a matrix) so they are not quite the same. Even if you did `as.vector()` on the `replicate()`, they are still slightly different. If the first three values in the sequence were "1, 2, 3", then you would know for sure the 4th number would be "4" with `replicate()`, but no such requirement would exist for the `rep()` method -- the next number could by any value 1-4. It all depends on exactly which type of "random" process you are trying to model.

Comment: @MrFlick, I want to randomly assign 40 subjects to one of 4 conditions (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4). Which of above can best randomly do that?

Comment: `sample(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: @Roman, the problem is that each of 4 conditions gets very different number of participants see: `table(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE)`.

Comment: @rnorouzian if you want to have 10 instances of each category, use `sample(rep(1:4, 10))` then

Comment: Well, statistically speaking if you want to "40 subjects to one of 4 conditions (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4)" then `sample(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE)` is the typical interpretation. If you have some other constraint, then you need to clearly state it. If it's required that all groups have exactly the same number of subjects, that's a different process.

Comment: @MrFlick, the problem is that each of 4 conditions gets very different number of participants see: `table(1:4, 40, replace = TRUE)`. So the constraint is to achieve equal number of 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions are not equal in any way.

---

#### 1. Type

> f1() outputs a vector, f2() outputs a matrix.

As @RicS said, the first returns a vector, the second one returns a matrix.

---

#### 2. Time

> f1() is almost 50x faster than f2().

The **differences in runtime** get clearer at a larger scale:

```
set.seed(1701)

# Functions
f1 <- function() { sample(rep(1:4, 10000)) }
f2 <- function() { c(replicate(10000, sample(1:4))) }

# Benchmark
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min         lq       mean     median        uq       max neval cld
 f1()   671.28   820.6755   983.9417   988.7985  1046.476  2320.425   100  a 
 f2() 40588.03 43241.0270 48796.0141 45612.0740 54431.890 71117.415   100   b
```

We see that `f1()` is clearly faster, exactly as @JosephClarkMcIntyre stated in the comments.

But are they at least equal in their *randomness*?
**Let's test that!**

---

#### 3. Randomness

> f2() is not random.

The Bartels rank test can test a series of numeric numbers for randomness vs. nonrandomness.

```
> randtests::bartels.rank.test(as.numeric(f1_result$value))

    Bartels Ratio Test

data:  as.numeric(f1_result$value)
statistic = -1.26, n = 40000, p-value = 0.2077
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

The p-value is > 0.05, therefore the null hypothesis was not rejected.
**The result of `f1()` is not nonrandom**. (this is not the same as being sure it is random)

```
> randtests::bartels.rank.test(as.numeric(f2_result$value))

    Bartels Ratio Test

data:  as.numeric(f2_result$value)
statistic = 50.017, n = 40000, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: nonrandomness
```

The p-value is < 0.05, therefore the null hypothesis was rejected.
**The result of `f1()` is nonrandom**.

This is also evident if you look at the result of the function itself.

```
> set.seed(1701)
> replicate(10, sample(1:4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    4    1    3    3    2    3    3    4     1
[2,]    3    1    2    1    4    3    2    2    3     4
[3,]    4    2    3    2    1    1    4    4    2     2
[4,]    2    3    4    4    2    4    1    1    1     3
```

It produces a matrix with ten columns, each column containing *exactly* the numbers 1:4. This is **not random**.

Comment: But, the `f1` consists of one random sample (n = 10000)  of 1 through 4. However, `f2` consists of 10000 times of random sampling (each time n = 4) of 1 through 4. I'm thinking these are two different things.

Comment: Right, but my question was that under the constraint that I need to have equal number of 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s, which process ensures better randomness?

Comment: Both functions above return n = 40000. Those are the exact functions you proposed. `f1()` samples from `rep(1:4, 10000)`, which is 10,000 x 1, 10,000 x 2, 10,000 x 3, 10,000 x 4. `f2()` samples from 1:4, but repeats it 10,000 times.

Comment: Therefore, `f2()` will **always** result in a distribution where each set of four people (1:4, 5:8, 9:12, ...) contains **all the four different groups**.  This is **not random**. `f1()` can result in a distribution where the four different groups are **randomly** distributed across your 40 people.

Comment: How about [**THIS**](https://www.randomizer.org/tutorial/lesson3.html#3)?

Comment: This is _randomized block design_ for tests, e.g., medical trials. It is used to control for confounding variables (e.g., gender). It produces a _less random_ distribution, but increases validity of tests, as (in many cases) variability inside one block is also reduced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186503/discussion-between-roman-and-rnorouzian).

Answer (score -1):

After having cleared what you mean in the comments, the two lines of code are basically equal in terms of randomness, as you will get 10 instances of each category (from 1 to 4).

The time to get the job done is essentially the same, as they are only 40 numbers in total.

However, `sample(rep(1:4, 10))` returns an integer *vector* of length 40, whereas `replicate(10, sample(1:4))` outputs a 4x10 *matrix*, in which you have the numbers from 1 to 4 drawn exactly once in each column.

Comment: They are not the same in terms of runtime.

Comment: I've tried that and they return the same runtime. Perhaps with larger sizes the runtime will be different, but what I wrote is referred only to these 40 numbers.

Comment: I believe `replicate(10, sample(1:4))` is preferred, because, it creates 10 blocks of randomly selected 1 through 4 and each block is randomized. If you matrix-ize the `matrix(sample(rep(1:4, 10)), 4, 10)` you see it can achieve the same thing as it is not block-zied.

Comment: @RicS It may not be _noticeable_, but it is there. Run `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sample(rep(1:4, 10)), replicate(10, sample(1:4)))` and you will see that the runtime of the second function is larger by a factor of ten.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with your comment and your answer, it is always a pleasure to learn something new!